# JS onmouseover does not work on div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So, I've a basic working example where I move my cursor/mouse, a div is generated with some styles, representing a wave like pattern based on the `clientX`.

It only works if I add an `addEventlistener` to `window`: `window.onmousemove= e => animationBubble(e.clientX);`

Don't ask me what this function do or please check if there's any issue in it or not! Let me tell you there is no issue/bug in the function, it's just a simple function which takes the mouse `clientX` pos and generate a div with certain classes and after some seconds removes it.

I found out it is useless to add an event Listener to the whole window, whereas I can save a lot of CPU usage if I add the `mousemove` `eventlistener` to the parent div. Indicating only generate divs if the user is hovering over the `parent div/container`. I was thinking to add this in my footer section to make it more interactive for the user.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("bubble_wrapper");

const animationBubble = (x) => {
  const bubble = document.createElement("div");
  bubble.className = "bubble";
  bubble.style.left = `${x}px`;
  wrapper.appendChild(bubble);
  setTimeout(() => wrapper.removeChild(bubble), 2000)
}

// wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
//     console.log("hi")
//     animationBubble(e.clientX);
// });

window.onmousemove = e => animationBubble(e.clientX);
```

```css
#bubble_wrapper {
  height           : 50%;
  width            : 100%;
  background-color : black;
  position         : fixed;
  bottom           : 0;
  overflow         : hidden;
  pointer-events   : none;
  }
.bubble {
  height           : max(300px, 30vw);
  width            : max(300px, 30vw);
  background-color : rgb(33, 150, 243);
  border-radius    : 100%;
  position         : absolute;
  left             : 50%;
  top              : 100%;
  animation        : wave 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes wave {
  from, to { transform: translate(-50%,   0%); }
  50%      { transform: translate(-50%, -20%); }
  }
```

```html
<div id="bubble_wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Provide thew debugging details in the question itself. You even received a warning before posting that a codepen must be accompanied with the code directly in the question itself

Comment: What do you think `pointer-events: none;` means?

Comment: @Keith well means that it hides the user pointer, right? well if so, I want to know how come it works for `window.addEventListener`. Sorry for the code pen it really went out my head that I can use the snippet tool T_T.

Comment: Nope, it just prevents pointer-events. Use `cursor: none;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the css class: `pointer-events: none;` with `cursor: none;` for `#bubble_wrapper` and it should work as expected:)

Hope I could help!